# How can I mock HttpResponse, an interface, with RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

Tags: kotlin, interface, mocking, mockito, httpresponse

I want to return 200 when these functions are called:

```
`when`(httpResponse.statusLine.statusCode).thenReturn(200)
```

the httpResponse is a mock created by

```
val httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse::class.java, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

My problem is that `httpResponse` is null when I use `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`. I guess this happens because HttpResponse is an interface(?).

If I skip `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`, i cant call any functions after the first `statusLine`

Is it possbile to mock an interface like this? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another mock:

```
val httpResponseStub = mock(HttpResponse::class.java);
val statusLineStub= mock(StatusLine::class.java);

when(statusLineStub.statusCode).thenReturn(200);
when(httpResponseStub.statusLine).thenReturn(statusLineStub);
```

step by step.